# GoDaddy database connectivity error while connecting to MySql database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

I am hosting a website on GoDaddy and getting database connectivity error while connecting to MySql database.
 The error is coming as "Connection must be valid and open."
 This error is coming while establishing the connection itself.

The language used is C# in MVC3.
 Database server : MySql

Following is the connection string that I am using to connect to database.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Application_Database" connectionString="Server=50.62.209.43;Protocol=TCP;Port=3306;Database=#####;Uid=#####;Pwd=######;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Further, I would like to inform that the same connection string (provided above) is working on my local system and other servers also, but it is not working on GoDaddy hosting server.**

Please help me out in this issue.

Comment: Have you seen this post on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465444/unable-to-connect-to-godaddy-mysql-database

Comment: Hi Brandon, thank you for reply. I have seen that link but I did not find any option to enable direct access for database as mentioend there...